# Scalatra - File Upload - File Size Too Large Error When It's Not

Tags: scala, file-upload, scalatra

I'm trying to upload a file using Scalatra Version: 2.4.0.

The file I'm trying to upload is only 181 bytes, but I keep getting my file size too large error message, but it's not too large. Everything is compiling and IntelliJ is showing no errors. When I upload, it shows the error page I'm expecting that says "File size too large!".

I've set up the MultipartConfig according to the Scalatra guide found here: [Scalatra File Upload](http://www.scalatra.org/2.4/guides/formats/upload.html).

Right now I'm just trying to get the upload working so I'm just printing to the console, I'll be working with the file in the request.

What am I missing here?

**Form**

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="file-selector">
      <input id="file-selector" name="the-file" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html($(this).val());" />
        Choose File
    </label>
    <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**Servlet**

```
trait UploadServlet extends BaseServlet with FileUploadSupport {

  error {
    case e:
      SizeConstraintExceededException => {
      RequestEntityTooLarge("File size too large!")
    }

  post("/upload") {
    Console.println("Yo Yo Ma")
  }

}
```

**Web App Launcher (WebappLauncher.scala)**

```
myApp.webapp.servletsMap.foreach { case (path, servlet) =>
  val holder = context.addServlet(servlet, path + "*")
  holder.getRegistration.setMultipartConfig(
    MultipartConfig(
      maxFileSize       = Some(5 * 1024 * 5000),
      fileSizeThreshold = Some(5 * 1024 * 5000)).toMultipartConfigElement)
}
```

Comment: Did you get any luck with this issue?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
trait UploadServlet extends ScalatraServlet with FileUploadSupport with FlashMapSupport {
  configureMultipartHandling(multipartConfig.copy(maxFileSize = Some(50*1024*1024)))
  ...
}
```